# Calculating a function over a large array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have written some code to determine an interpolation matrix over a grid of points. I originally wrote the code in matlab, where under the specified parameters it took just over 2 minutes. The equivalent code in Python however takes 40minutes!

I was expecting Python to be slower, but not be such an amount! Any feedback on the code is much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

def g(x, y):
    gx = -x * (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    gy = -y * (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    return np.array((gx, gy))

def wendland(r):
    if r < 1:
        return ((1-r)**4)*(4*r+1)
    else:
        return 0

def make_collocation_points(h, x1, x2, y1, y2):
    i = 0
    x = []
    y = []

    for j in range(x1,x2+1):
        for k in np.arange(y1, y2, h):
            if LA.norm(g(j*h, k*h) - (j*h, k*h)) > 0.00001: # Don't accept values on the chain recurrent set!
                x.append(j*h)
                y.append(k*h)

                i += 1

    return x, y, i

def get_aij(x, y, n):
    a = np.zeros((n,n))
    for j in range(0, n):
        for k in range(0, n):
            a[j, k] = (
                wendland(LA.norm(g(x[j], y[j]) - g(x[k], y[k])))
                - wendland(LA.norm(g(x[j], y[j]) - np.array([x[k], y[k]])))
                - wendland(LA.norm([x[j], y[j]] - g(x[k], y[k])))
                + wendland(LA.norm(np.array([x[j], y[j]]) - np.array([x[k], y[k]])))
            )
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = 0.11
    x1, x2 = -15, 15
    y1, y2 = -15, 15

    x, y, n = make_collocation_points(h, x1, x2, y1, y2)
    a = get_aij(x, y, n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both Matlab and Numpy, your indexed loops are not the right way to express vectorized operations. You should adopt a strong bias against loops and individual element indexing, learn how broadcasting works, and pass around `ndarray`s instead of lists.

Based on the above, a potential vectorized solution - with a regression test to ensure that the results have not changed - is

```py
from numbers import Real
from typing import Sequence, Union

import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from scipy.stats import describe


EPSILON = 1e-12


def g(xy: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return -xy * np.sum(xy**2, axis=0)


def wendland(r: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    r = norm(r, axis=0)
    out = (1 - r)**4 * (1 + 4*r)
    out[r >= 1] = 0
    return out


def make_collocation_points(h: Real, x1: int, x2: int, y1: int, y2: int) -> np.ndarray:
    j = np.arange(x1, x2+1)
    k = np.arange(y1, y2, h)
    jk = np.stack(np.meshgrid(k, j)) * h

    # Don't accept values on the chain recurrent set!
    g_norm = norm(g(jk) - jk, axis=0)
    jk = jk[::-1, g_norm > 1e-5]

    return jk


def get_aij(xy: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # broadcast to get the effect of xj, xk, yj, yk
    xyj, xyk = np.broadcast_arrays(
        xy[:, np.newaxis, :],
        xy[:, :, np.newaxis],
    )

    gj = g(xyj)
    gk = g(xyk)

    return (
        + wendland(gj - gk)  - wendland(xyj - gk)
        - wendland(gj - xyk) + wendland(xyj - xyk)
    )


def assert_close(
    a: Union[Real, np.ndarray],
    b: Union[Real, Sequence[Real]],
) -> None:
    assert np.all(np.isclose(a, b, rtol=0, atol=EPSILON))


def regression_test() -> None:
    h = 0.11
    n = 2  # 15 is way too slow
    x1, x2 = -n, n
    y1, y2 = -n, n

    xy = make_collocation_points(h, x1, x2, y1, y2)
    assert xy.shape == (2, 185)
    stats = describe(xy.T)
    assert_close(stats.minmax[0], (-0.22, -0.22))
    assert_close(stats.minmax[1], (+0.22, +0.2156))
    assert_close(stats.mean, (0, -2.2e-3))
    assert_close(stats.variance, (0.02433152173913048, 0.016781450543478273))

    a = get_aij(xy)
    assert a.shape == (185, 185)
    stats = describe(a.flatten())
    assert_close(stats.minmax[0], -0.17266964737638246)
    assert_close(stats.minmax[1], +1.10925185890418380)
    assert_close(stats.mean, 0.11771392866408713)
    assert_close(stats.variance, 0.061445578720171375)


def demo() -> None:
    h = 0.11
    n = 10
    x1, x2 = -n, n
    y1, y2 = -n, n

    xy = make_collocation_points(h, x1, x2, y1, y2)
    print(describe(xy.T))

    a = get_aij(xy)
    print(describe(a.flatten()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    regression_test()
    demo()
```

I don't have a whole lot of patience for long execution runs, but for n=10 the demo finishes in about five seconds even though it produces 14,607,684 elements. A quick-and-dirty `timeit` produces:

```
old, n=2: 1.433 s
new, n=2: 0.007 s
old, n=3: 6.206 s
new, n=3: 0.035 s
old, n=4: 18.033 s
new, n=4: 0.099 s
old, n=5: 43.935 s
new, n=5: 0.224 s
old, n=6: 90.451 s
new, n=6: 0.459 s
old, n=7: 161.559 s
new, n=7: 0.878 s
```